# linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios

I have app it's working good , but i am add chat view ( Xib - .h - .m ) files and every thing it's ok, but when i try to run it on my iPhone i got this problem:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 

    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFURLConnectionOperation._totalBytesRead in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFURLConnectionOperation._uploadProgress in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFURLConnectionOperation._downloadProgress in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFURLConnectionOperation._authenticationChallenge in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFURLConnectionOperation._cacheResponse in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFURLConnectionOperation._redirectResponse in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFURLConnectionOperation in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFURLConnectionOperation in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFHTTPRequestOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFHTTPRequestOperation2.o
duplicate symbol _AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey in:
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLConnectionOperation.o
    /Users/ZzXzZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/9otk-exeoubkkvfbvbkejxccjhfiqjkrw/Build/Intermediates/9otk.build/Debug-iphoneos/9otk.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFURLResponseSerialization2.o
ld: 71 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: i clean my project more and more and i delete DerivedData but no way

Comment: guess, you must have two `AFURLConnectionOperation` in your `Xcode` project

Comment: yah i use 2 and i have it

Comment: delete one file, then try

Comment: same no new i clean now project

Comment: may be armv7 architecture not supported. Add armv7 architecture in valid architectures. AFHTTPRequestOperation have duplicate files delete the duplicate one.

Comment: vishnu i need to be 2 file there is different in lines some of AFHTTPRequestxxx2.h m change to another request

Answer (score 0):

From the log it seems that you have renamed the AFxxxxx.h[m] files with a suffix 2.
Try removing those extra files(AFxxxxx2.h[m]). Clean the project and build again. Good luck.

Comment: but AFxxx.m different from AFxxx2.m so i can't remove any files all my problem because i have 2 folder of AFNetworking

Comment: @user3634298 You should delete one of your AFNetworking framework from project, and leave only 1, because there is duplicate classes in your project in other case